# N*N 2d grid matrix rotation 90deg in python

Tags: python

I want to rotate a matrix of N*N size M amount of times 90deg.

This is my code so far. I am taking in N grid size, and then converting it to a flatlist to find its orientation so I can figure out the amount of required rotations.

I then call my rotate method based on how many times I need to rotate the grid.

```
N = int(input())

measurements = []
for i in range(N):
    item = list(map(int, input().split()))
    measurements.append(item)

flatList = [element for innerList in measurements for element in innerList]
 
# print(flatList.index(1))
def findRotation():
    if flatList.index(1) == 0:
        return 0
    elif flatList.index(1) == N-1:
        return 3
    elif flatList.index(1) == N**2 -1:
        return 2
    elif flatList.index(1) == N*(N-1):
        return 1
    else:
        print("uh")

num1 = findRotation()

def rotate90(measurements, N):
    
    left, right = 0, N - 1

    while left < right: 
        for i in range(left-right):
            top, bottom = left, right
            topLeft = measurements[top][left + i]
            
            measurements[top][left+i] = measurements[bottom-i][left]
           
            measurements[bottom-i][left] = measurements[bottom][right - i]
            
            measurements[bottom][right -i] = measurements[top+i][right]
            
            measurements[top+i][right] = topLeft
        right -= 1
        left += 1
        return measurements

def runIt(number):
    for _ in range(number):
        print(rotate90(measurements, N))
    


runIt(num1)
```

Input:

```
3
4 3 1
6 5 2
9 7 3
```

output:

```
[[4, 3, 1], [6, 5, 2], [9, 7, 3]]
[[4, 3, 1], [6, 5, 2], [9, 7, 3]]
[[4, 3, 1], [6, 5, 2], [9, 7, 3]]
```

Expected:

```
1 2 3
3 5 7
4 6 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is `rotate()` function that takes two parameters - matrix and how many times it needs to be rotated (we can use modulo 4 here, because rotating the matrix 4 times is no-op):

```py
def rotate(m, n):
    for i in range(n % 4):
        m = list(zip(*m[::-1]))
    return m


def pretty_print_matrix(m):
    for row in m:
        print(*row, sep=" ")


matrix = [[4, 3, 1], [6, 5, 2], [9, 7, 3]]
print("Initial matrix")
pretty_print_matrix(matrix)
print()

# rotate matrix 3 times
matrix = rotate(matrix, 3)

pretty_print_matrix(matrix)
```

Prints:

```
Initial matrix
4 3 1
6 5 2
9 7 3

1 2 3
3 5 7
4 6 9
```